# How to use $addToSet become an array with objects?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a lots of documents.

My document structure just like this:

Here is an api can get the json data:

https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=TaipeiEast&theater=Centuryasia

[image]

I want to query my data without duplicate `enName`, so i try to use `$addToSet`

Here is my query command:

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
        "theater": "Centuryasia"
      }
  },
  { "$unwind": '$movie' },
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "enName": {
        "$addToSet": "$movie.enName" 
       },
       "photoHref": {
         "$addToSet": "$movie.photoHref" 
       }
    } 
  }
])
```

The query result will like this:
[image]

I want the structure can be like:

```
movie: [
  { enName: "value", photoHref: "value"},
  { enName: "value", photoHref: "value"},
  ...
]
```

I try to add `$push`

```
db.getCollection('Keelung').aggregate([
      { "$match": {
            "theater": "Centuryasia"
          }
      },
      { "$unwind": '$movie' },
      { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "enName": {
            "$addToSet": "$movie.enName" 
           },
           "photoHref": {
             "$addToSet": "$movie.photoHref" 
           }
        },
        "movie": {
          "$push": {
            "enName": "$enName",
            "photoHref": "$photoHref",
          }
        } 
      }
    ])
```

It is not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your sample collection instead of screen shot

Comment: Of course, i has an api can be use https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=TaipeiEast&theater=Centuryasia, the json structure is the same as my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "theater": "Centuryasia" }},
  { "$unwind": "$movie" },
  { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "theater": { "$first": "$theater" },
      "phone": { "$first": "$phone" },
      "geometry": { "$first": "$geometry" },
      "theaterPhoto": { "$first": "$theaterPhoto" },
      "address": { "$first": "$address" },
      "theaterCn": { "$first": "$theaterCn" },
      "movie": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "enName": "$movie.enName",
          "photoHref": "$movie.photoHref"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , it saves me a day !  So my mistake is set  `$addToSet` with wrong format. I get it now, thank you very much !